# Running apt get in non interactive manner

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I've a custom Debian package that has couple of questions like `do I overwrite the config file?`. I want to run the apt get command with all prompts being answered yes or y automatically. I can't find such an option for apt. Is this possible or do I need to change the Debian file's way of working? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with [expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module.

Comment: Expect throws error on apt. Says it works for command n some others but not apt